# Update node app dependency without restarting node app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, irc

I'm trying to build a chat bot to be used on twitch.tv to connect to irc that listens for commands typed like `!command` at which point it will do some sort of action.

My first thought was to use a separate file to store an object containing expected commands and the proper responses, that way if I want to add new commands on the fly I can do so, but I need to figure out a way to get the imported commands object to update with newly added commands without stopping the node server that is connected to irc.

Would it just be easier to create a mongodb collection containing commands that I can check against each time a new command comes in (I will be using mongodb later on for storing some info with the bot)

Just trying to figure out what the best course of action now would be

Comment: Just make the "separate file" a module that grabs a separate file and generates an object, you can then update that object throughout the lifetime of the application, and any time it is updated, write those changes to the file so that on next boot it'l pull the file in with all the changes. I wonder if there's an existing npm module that does this.

Comment: And, there is. :) https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json-db

Comment: Not having looked at the inner-workings of that module, I don't know how it might handle updates from an external source (which I assume is what you're after).  You could either go the mongodb route (which might be recommended) or you could use the `fs` module to `watch()` a text file for changes, and on change, re-read it.

Comment: That's true, i have no idea if it would catch the json file being manually modified outside of node, though I didn't think that's what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like you need a database, however, you can use that json file as a database using the [node-json-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json-db) module.

```
var JsonDB = require('node-json-db');
var db = new JsonDB("commands", true); // targets file in same directory named "command.json"
var commands = db.getData("/commands");

// ... as a callback somewhere...
db.push("/commands", {test:"test", foo: {bar:["apple"]}});

commands = db.getData("/commands");
```